LTspice: -- Syntax Error -- Unknown symbol: t
I am trying to simulate in LTSpice, an NTC sensor with the characteristic curve:
R={Rf}*exp({B}*(1/(T+273.15)-1/({Tf}+273.15)))

and in a simple circuit that I show in the figure, the parameters between curly brackets seem to interpret their values ​​well, but I don't know how to define the variable T so that in the simulation it takes values ​​from 20 to 100 in intervals of 5.
I have tried putting it between curly brackets, without them, with the directive .dc T 20 100 5. But I can't get rid of the error:
ntc: -- Syntax Error --
Unknown symbol: t


Could someone tell me how to solve it?


I don't know how to define the variable T so that in the simulation it
takes values ​​from 20 to 100 in intervals of 5.

Try this...
.step param t list 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 65 70 75 80 85 90 95 100

Or this...
.step param t 20 100 5

Both of the above will run one simulation for each value of t.
If you want t to change over time during a single simulation run then you can make "t" into a net name label, put it on a voltage source, and use the advanced options to make a piece wise linear voltage source.  Then do your calculations using that voltage as the input variable.

I believe, you need to call t a recognizable LTspice variable name i.e. use TEMP.
Please refer to this: Managing temperature in LTSPICE: -


This is how I simulate a NTC:

In the plot it will show the resistance in kV instead of kOhm.
When you know which part of the curve you are going to use, you'll need to add more values in that part of the PWL to get more accuracy.

Both answers from @user4574 using “.step param……..” and the answer from @Andy aka giving a variable name recognizable to LTSpice as TEMP solve the error.
I will use this model for the circuit that I indicate below, in case it is useful.

It aims to adapt a voltage output and linearize a resistive temperature sensor.
It is possible to adapt the output between 0 – 10V or by varying resistors you get an output between 0 – 5 V. but from the circuit with the operational amplifier as a non-inverting amplifier, the signal is not linearized.
To linearize it I think I will have to use complex software equations.
I will try the @hennep potentiometer simulation system.
Thanks to everyone for the answers

(The sincere way to tell you think an answer helpful is up-voting it. When you don't expext an answer to surpass the one you find most helpful, you should accept it.)
